# How do I compare the contents of two Google Protocol Buffer messages for equality?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I can't seem to find a comparison method in the API. I have these two messages, and they have a lot of  different values that sometimes drill down to more values (for example, I have a Message that has a string, an int, and a custom_snapshot, where custom_snapshot is comprised of an int, a string, and so on). I want to see if these two messages are the same. I don't want to compare each value one by one since that will take a while, so I was wondering if there was a quick way to do this in Python?

I tried doing messageA.debugString() == messageB.debugString(), but apparently there is no debugString method that I could access when I tried.

Comment: Python protobufs implement `__str__`, so you can get a debug string using `str(message)`. But text conversion is slow. If it's just for comparison, might as well use the binary serialization instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

protocol buffers have a method `SerializeToString(daterministic=True)`

Use it to compare your messages.

Comment: This works as long as neither message contains unknown fields (i.e. you didn't receive the messages from a future version of the program where new fields have been added in the `.proto` file). That said, if unknown fields are present, there is actually no "correct" way to compare for equality.

Comment: @KentonVarda Taking into account, that proto buffer is a method to serialize an object into stream, I guess, there shall be a way to get bytes of that stream and perform simple comparison with another one. Saying that, I do not have working example to prove it is true.

Comment: The problem with comparing bytes is that fields are allowed to appear in any order on the wire, so you might get a false negative even when the messages really are the same. If you just serialized the messages yourself, then the serializer will always put the fields in the same order. But this doesn't apply to unknown fields, and in general it's impossible to "canonicalize" protobuf data when you don't have the schema. So if there are unknown fields, you might get a false negative.

Comment: If you're going to use `SerializeToString` for this, you should at least pass `deterministic=True` in order to enforce a deterministic ordering for mapping fields.

Answer (score 0):

[`google.protobuf.text_format.MessageToString`](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/text_format.html#google.protobuf.text_format.MessageToString) converts the proto message to its text format, so it's probably easier to inspect any diff (if any) than the binary string produced by `SerializeToString`. It also has many options, e.g. to ignore unknown fields.

Answer (score -2):

You can compare two proto objects using equals method

For example :

```
 Object1.equals(Object2)
```

It will check content of Object1 equals to content of Object2. If you are using enum in the any of the proto then should maintain sequence . Otherwise it will give u false as sequence does not match

Comment: Not working on Python, gets AttributeError