# Python equivalence of C++ protobuf message differencer

Tags: python, c++, protocol-buffers

I am trying to compare two protobuf messages in Python for equality, ignoring the order elements in lists and so on.

For C++, I found the MessageDifferencer (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.util.message_differencer)

Now I'm looking for something similar in Python, but can't really find anything. Any suggestions what I can use?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare the contents of two Google Protocol Buffer messages for equality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296221/how-do-i-compare-the-contents-of-two-google-protocol-buffer-messages-for-equalit)

Comment: anybody has java version?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anything exists. You can probably wrap the C++ implementation in python using [CLIF](https://github.com/google/clif) or something similar.

I implemented a version myself (with only basic set of features) in https://github.com/dayfine/proto-matcher